# VB.Net: string property from an openFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, properties, openfiledialog

I am creating an userControl and want it to have a string property that can be filled in using an openFileDialog in design time.

You know, with those little '...' beside the Visual Studio property textbox so that one can browse to a file if needed.

I can't figure out how to achieve that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific of what you have tried and such?

Comment: Anthony,
I don't know how to insert a code snippet properly here... I've tried the following:

Private ofd As Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    Public Property SomeString() As Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        Get
            Return ofd
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog)
            ofd = value
        End Set
    End Property

I also tried IO.File instead of OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileNameEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.filenameeditor(v=vs.110).aspx) Class.

Add a **Reference** to `System.Design`, then use code like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

Public Class ucThingaMaBob

    Private _FileName As String

    ' Add a Reference to System.Design

    <EditorAttribute(GetType(FileNameEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>
    Public Property FileName() As String
        Get
            Return _FileName
        End Get
        Set
            _FileName = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Now when you click on the "..." in the FileName entry an OpenFileDialog will appear.